# Javascript gallery slide slowing down towards the ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, gallery, slide

I have a problem with a really good JS Gallery, this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/p44af/

I have edited and adjusted it as I needed it, but I noticed that sliding towards the end, or coming back to the beginning, the "sliding speed" decelerates. I want to get rid of it, as it becomes extremely slow when the gallery arrives to its extremes.

For example, if I have 40 images, when arrived to the 30th it begins to gradually slow down, and to arrive from 35 to 40 it takes forever.
I suspect it has something to do with the "CompensationSpeed", but I have tried and failed many times to edit it.

Help anyone? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the effect you want, change the line `posX += (- MouseRelXpos - posX) / 14` to `posX += (- MouseRelXpos - posX) / 2`. This will remove the slowing down at the edges.

[Updated JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/p44af/156/)